# Custom Action doesn't show on form? Could it be infopath?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, infopath, custom-actions, custom-action

I have a list where I customized the forms using InfoPath.

I then created a custom action for my display and edit form ribbons in SharePoint Designer that prints the item being viewed / edited (using the command `javascript:window.print()` in the Navigate to URL section), however, the custom action button is not showing on the forms.

I added a View Ribbon Custom Action and that shows `OK` on the list view and I tried these custom actions on another list that hasn't had forms updated using InfoPath and it works exactly as expected.

Does customizing forms using InfoPath impact the use of Custom Actions?

Has any experienced this before and know of how I may be able to fix this issue for this list?

Kind regards,

John

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the custom action can work well with InfoPath forms.

You can refer to this similar thread

[Custom Actions and InfoPath](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/c6afbc48-90cc-4db0-9808-f181c121c7d1/)

Still you can try steps mentioned in below URL.

[Add custom commands on Infopath browser form ribbon](https://web.archive.org/web/20140323093104/http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/03/add-custom-commands-on-infopath-browser-form-ribbon/)